# Autodesk is directing all support questions to Stack Overflow

Tags: support

While reviewing a "me-too" non-answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261129/viewer-renders-everything-in-black-and-changed-model-tree-information), I was baffled by this reply:

[image]

Under which conditions is it acceptable for a company to send their customers to SO, treating it as their help desk? I suggested to delete the comment and contact the company representative, who left a comment. Is there anything else I should have done?

Comment: Well, their Get Help page consists solely of a page telling people to ask on Stack Overflow: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/support/get-help , with no other means of contacting them listed, so that's great.

Comment: @BradLarson Yup, I was hoping for some guidelines, what we should do in such a case. Especially, what to tell new members, who don't have a reputation score to write a comment. I am not wasting my time, contacting the company and tell them, they shouldn't do this. But marked as duplicate, so be it.

Comment: It's still a useful observation, and we can use it. A lot (but be warned: **not all**) of questions that [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7745569/eason-kang) answered are off-topic for Stack Overflow, either because they ask about specific software features and problems, or they mention some programming but do not post an MCVE.

Comment: @BradLarson I found their [social media list](https://www.autodesk.com/social-media).